# Optimizing dfs in django

Tags: django, postgresql, depth-first-search

I have users in some kind of a tree that represents my affiliate system. I need to get and count all users that are under me in the tree (my partners). I've implemented modified version of deep first search algorithm but it works slow because it makes a lot of calls to database to get each user and their partners. How I can optimize all this process to work faster?

`User` model

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, blank=True)
    invited_by = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    partners = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True) # here are all user's partners
    wallet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    turnover = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

That's my dfs function. It accepts current `User` object and returns list of users that are under him in this tree

```
def dfsgetlist(user):
    q = []
    for i in user.partners.all():
        if i != user and i != user.invited_by:
            q += dfsgetlist(i)
    return q + [user]
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) vs making your own solution

Comment: @Jason, I've already fixed it by changing algo to BFS. It performs approximately log(N) queries to database (max depth of the tree). I know that it could be N also, but on practice it's not possible to build such refferal tree

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has solved their own question in the comments / it was too broad to begin with.